# Xenomai-Implementing a RTOS emulation framework on GNU/Linux

Tags: kernel, dpkg, compiling, make

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Linux kernel 4.9.38

Xenomai-3.0.5

ipipe-core-4.9.38-x86-3.patch
Installing Xenomai 3.0.5 User space libraries

```
$cd xenomai-3.0.5

$./configure --with-pic --with-core=cobalt --enable-smp --disable-tls --enable-dlopen-libs --disable-clock-monotonic-raw

config.status: creating include/smokey/Makefile
config.status: creating include/trank/Makefile
config.status: creating include/trank/posix/Makefile
config.status: creating include/trank/native/Makefile
config.status: creating include/trank/rtdm/Makefile
config.status: creating include/xenomai/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/doxygen/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/doxygen/xeno3prm-common.conf
config.status: creating doc/doxygen/xeno3prm-html.conf
config.status: creating doc/doxygen/xeno3prm-latex.conf
config.status: creating doc/gitdoc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/asciidoc/Makefile
config.status: creating include/xeno_config.h
config.status: include/xeno_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

$make CFLAGS=-no-pie -j`nproc` && make install


make[1]: Entering directory '/home/efdas/usr/src/xenomai-3.0.5/scripts'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/efdas/usr/src/xenomai-3.0.5/scripts'
Making all in testsuite
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/efdas/usr/src/xenomai-3.0.5/testsuite'
Making all in latency
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/efdas/usr/src/xenomai-3.0.5/testsuite/latency'
Making all in latency
/bin/bash: line 20: cd: latency: No such file or directory
Makefile:424: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/efdas/usr/src/xenomai-3.0.5/testsuite/latency'
Makefile:420: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/efdas/usr/src/xenomai-3.0.5/testsuite'
Makefile:460: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You've not provided details that match a Ubuntu product, you're using a Debian kernel? and using a unsupported & non-updated Ubuntu *bionic* system, which implies you're using a Ubuntu based system on a device, and not a Ubuntu ISO/product.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are trying to use [Xenomai](https://xenomai.org/) on a 4.9.38 Linux kernel. Since Ubuntu 18.04 only supports 4.15, 4.18, 5.0 and 5.4. I am also assuming, that you are using a custom kernel.

For Xenomai to work, you need a supported Linux kernel version and a **compatible glibc**. If you are already on a custom kernel and choose Ubuntu 18.04 because the glibc is compatible: Why are using a 4 year alt version of Xenomai?

I would recommend to use a [current version of Xenomai](https://source.denx.de/Xenomai/xenomai) combined with a current Linux Kernel (currently only 5.4 is [supported](https://xenomai.org/downloads/ipipe/v5.x/x86/) for x86). The Ubuntu provided kernel wouldn't do the trick, because they are also patched and the Xenomai patches typically only apply on the upstream kernel.

Regarding the issue with **testsuite/latency**: The testsuites are not required for a working Xenomai. So there is no harm in disabling them. However using the testsuites can be particularly useful to identify issues with the glibc compatibility.

Just to be clear - Patching the Linux kernel and installing the Xenomai copperplate extension for glibc is only the beginning. You need to **rewrite** the applications you want to use real-time behavior of Xenomai.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the HWE kernel will be using the 5.4 kernel (ie. the kernel stack from 20.04 is the 18.04.5 HWE kernel).  The kernels you list are 4.15 (18.04), 4.18 (18.04.2), 5.0 (18.04.3), & 5.3 (18.04.4) missing 18.04.5 and later...

Comment: That was a typo...

Comment: FYI: 5.3 **was** a supported kernel at 18.04.4; it was replaced at upgrade to 5.4 at 18.04.5...  If you're listing all kernels, 5.3 & 5.4 **were** both supported

Comment: In any case... it is not 4.9.38, which was used in the questions.